# Filtrar datas em array

Tags: javascript, firebase

Atualmente eu uso o firebase como minha base de dados. Eu preciso pegar uma coleção e trazer os dados de um mês especifico conforme dois campos da minha coleção. O firebase não nós deixa fazer querys com campos diferentes logo eu optei por trazer tudo do ano de 2018 e filtrar no meu array o mês especifico.

Eu faço a seguinte query no firebase:

```
  let start = new Date('2018-01-01');
  let end = new Date('2018-12-31');
  let ref = db.collection('eventos').where("dt_inicio", ">", start).where("dt_inicio", "<", end).orderBy("dt_inicio", "asc");


  ref.get()
  .then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
     console.log(doc.data());
    });
  });
```

Ele me retorna para o doc.data(), e dando um console.log eu tenho o seguinte retorno.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de filtrar a data inicio e a data fim pelo mês de 08/2018.

Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando JS puro, você pode usar uma combinação de `filter` e alguns métodos do objeto `Date`. Entendi que você quer filtrar os resultados por mês e ano, então ficaria assim:

```js
// Recebe o array com os resultados, o mês e o ano no padrão JS. Volta um array filtrado
function filtrarResultados(array, mes, ano) {
    return array.filter(resultado => {
        // Salva o mês e ano de cada campo para poder verificar
        const dt_inicioMes = resultado.dt_inicio.getMonth()
        const dt_inicioAno = resultado.dt_inicio.getFullYear()
        const dt_fimMes = resultado.dt_fim.getMonth()
        const dt_fimAno = resultado.dt_fim.getFullYear()
        return dt_inicioMes == mes && dt_fimMes == mes && dt_inicioAno == ano && dt_fimAno == ano
    })
}
```

Esse trecho de código irá filtrar e retornará um array somente com os resultados que tiverem `dt_inicio` e `dt_fim` em um dado mês e um dado ano.

Comment: Creio que o que ele deseja é filtrar diretamente.

Comment: A bronca é que o Firebase não permite isso.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries